# What is the best practice to export and import mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been working in a project which involves Mysql and PHP. While creating package for testing i have exported mysql database as sql file from MySql Workbench and imported into linux machine's mysql server with

```
mysql>source mydatabase.sql;
```

is this the correct way to export and import mysql database?. And also the database file contains creation of schema, inserting data, and creating indexes scripts. Importing takes long time with this file. My immediate manager suggests me to export without indices and import database, then execute index creation scripts. Is this is the correct way? Does indices takes long time while importing database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds to me that either way, your time will be consumed with indexing the table.  In any case, this does appear to be correct.  You only other alternative would be to do a SELECT INTO another database.  That may or may not even be possible.  But it should save time.

Answer (score 1):

Export depends on the MySQL version/vendor you are running !

- MySQL(older versions) - uses mysqldump
- MySQL(percona) - uses XtraBackup
- MySQL(EE - 5.6) - uses MySQL Enterprise Backup which is more complex
  and much faster.

Fastest way is to avoid mysqldump.

I like Percona more then the others ! 
Another way but is more advanced i think is to create the DB on the destination server, and copy the database files directly. Assuming user has access to the destination server's mysql directory:
**As root user:**

```
[root@server-A]# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
[root@server-A]# cd /var/lib/mysql/[databasename]
[root@server-A]# scp * user@otherhost:/var/lib/mysql/[databasename]
[root@server-A]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Important things here are: Stop mysqld on both servers before copying DB files, make sure the file ownership and permissions are correct on the destination before starting mysqld on the destination server.

```
[root@server-B]# chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/[databasename]/*
[root@server-B]# chmod 660 /var/lib/mysql/[databasename]/*
[root@server-B]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

With time being your priority here, the use of compression will depend on whether the time lost waiting for compression/decompression (with something like gzip) will be greater than the time wasted transmitting uncompressed data; that is, the speed of your connection.

Answer (score 1):

[Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server) comes with a modified mysqldump tool so you can choose the [--innodb-optimize-keys](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/management/innodb_expanded_fast_index_creation.html) option. This exports the tables, data, and index definitions like stock mysqldump, but during import it defers creation of secondary indexes until *after* the data has been loaded into the table. This takes advantage of InnoDB's [fast index creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-create-index.html) feature.

Another option is to use a physical backup tool, like [Percona XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) (as user @Up_One) mentioned. This means that the full data files are backed up, including the indexes. On restore, nothing needs to be rebuilt, because the indexes are already populated. There are pros and cons to using physical backup tools too, but restore time is a big advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use mysqldump! (Check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)